# LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemecpbgposter.sty' not found

Tags: beamerposter

I am new here...

Trying to work on a beamerposter, I am getting the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemecpbgposter.sty' not found.
```

While using this template from here:

https://github.com/brookst/poster/blob/master/poster.tex

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you copied all the doc in the local folder or only `poster.tex`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the file `beamerthemecpbgposter.sty` is in the git repository you should have it on your local folder.

You can clone the repository with:

```
git clone https://github.com/brookst/poster.git ./
```

All the files will be copied in the current folder. After this a compilation will not raised this error.

If this error is still present, your LaTeX execution should not contain the working directory.

Comment: I have now copied the enire doc in my local folder, but I get the same error. Can you say what is the problem?

Comment: @mico what's your OS and it's version?

Comment: windows 7, 2009

Comment: @mico I've compiled it with TL2009 without any trouble. The `poster.tex` your trying to compile is the one in the same folder as every files and not the first one?